# Js split array obj

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have an array formed by a series of objs, I would like to make sure to assign an object to a variable.
If the object doesn't exist I would like to assign `{}` (empty obj).

Can you give me some advice?

```js
let a = [
{
  username: 'james.bond',
  name: 'James Bond',
  email: 'james.bond.xx@xxx.xxx',
},
{
  username: 'sherlock.holmes',
  name: 'Sherlock Holmes',
  email: 'sherlock.holmes.xx@xxx.xxx',
},
{
  name: 'Shinichi Kudo',
  email: 'shinichi.kudo.xx@xxx.xxx',
  badgeText: '21',
  badgeColor: '#fff',
  badgeBackground: '#25dbd2',
  joined: 'Joined at Jun 31, 2021',
  circle: ['transparent', 'transparent'],
},
{
  name: 'Arthur Conan Doyle',
  email: 'arthur.conan.doyle.xx@xxx.xxx',
  circle: ['transparent', 'transparent'],
},
  ];
        
   const [b = {}, c = [] ] = a;

console.log(b, c);//b=a[0], c=[a[1],a[2],a[3]]
```

Comment: What? Please add an expected output to your question, it is currently not possible to understand your desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const [ b = {}, c = {}, d = {} ] = a;
```

Or:

```
const [ b = {}, ...c] = a;
```

`c` will be an array contains the rest of `a` except the first element.

Comment: Thank you for replying I changed the question slightly, can you help me?

Comment: @Paul this might help: `const [ b = {}, ...c] = a`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let a = [{
    username: 'james.bond',
    name: 'James Bond',
    email: 'james.bond.xx@xxx.xxx',
  },
  {
    username: 'sherlock.holmes',
    name: 'Sherlock Holmes',
    email: 'sherlock.holmes.xx@xxx.xxx',
  }
];

const [b = {}, c = {}, d = {} ] = a;//a.map(x => x)

console.log(b, c, d);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying I changed the question slightly, can you help me?